# Django date format 'dd-mm-yyyy'

Tags: python, django, django-forms, date-format, django-settings

Is there any way I can get django to store my data in postgresql as 'dd-mm-yyyy' (if required) and have the django forms validate for 'dd-mm-yyyy'?

*(I have tried without much success things like:*

```py
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%d-%m-%Y')
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
```

*And done a lot of googling but no success :(*

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that I needed both the ISO and UK date formats in the `settings.py` file like so:

```
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%d-%m-%Y','%Y-%m-%d')
```

and then the forms.py adjusted to the following:

```
class ClientDetailsForm(ModelForm):
    date_of_birth = DateField(input_formats=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS)
    class Meta:
        model = ClientDetails
```

Why `USE_L10N = True` can't just do this I don't know!

*[Thanks to [this](http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/12161ac3e8f8c96e) and [this](http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/33b718278788170d)]*

Comment: You don't have the US format as you said, you've got the UK and ISO formats.

Comment: working fine and date saving to database. but Now date is not rendering to template

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#date

Answer (score 23):

`DATE_INPUT_FORMATS` in settings.py has no effect with `USE_I18N = True`. This is because django will load specific format for active locale. Django ships with format definitions for many different locales.

You can override django default format definitions:

```
mysite/
    formats/
        __init__.py
        en/
            __init__.py
            formats.py
```

As described in django documentation: [Creating custom formats file](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/formatting/#creating-custom-format-files)

Comment: does `USE_L10N = True` have any effect on `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS`

Comment: If `USE_L10N = False` then django will not use any formats from your settings. `USE_L10N = True` enables you to set formats in your settings.py. And `USE_I18N = True` goes even further and enables locale specific formats.

Comment: Your first sentence (`DATE_INPUT_FORMATS in settings.py has no effect with USE_I18N = True.`) is the crux of the matter. Just like mentioned in docs, you have to add your `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS` etc into that `formats.py` file.

Answer (score 13):

In [Sevenearths answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4884923/243925) there's the comment

> Why `USE_L10N = True` can't just do this I don't know!

The documentation says that `USE_L10N = True` is the default setting, but to get UK dates to work the [`LANGUAGE_CODE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#std:setting-LANGUAGE_CODE) must also be changed from its default setting of `en-us` to `en-GB`.

Once changed, date fields automatically accept the formats "dd/mm/yyyy" and "yyyy-mm-dd" (and possibly others, I've not tested them all) without needing to set `input_formats = settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS` in every form date field.

Answer (score 4):

I used below code that worked on Both Add and Edit Form Case.

**in settings.py**

```
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%d/%m/%Y','%d-%m-%Y','%Y-%m-%d')
```

**in forms.py**

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    issue_date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(format = '%d/%m/%Y'), input_formats=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS)
```

Answer (score 3):

This might not be the answer to the exact question, but since I got here... I would suggest using a date widget, and let Django save the date the way it understands it. Define the field in your form like so:

```
import datetime
from django import forms

def last_years():
    first_year = datetime.datetime.now().year - 6
    return list(range(first_year + 7, first_year, -1))

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    # This is it... it's user friendly, and can't go wrong parsing it
    date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(years = last_years()))
```

If you got it into a date field of the Django Model, then the only problem left would be format the output representation. Am I right?

Comment: A lot has changed since I asked this question. I think your answer would be perfect for 1.10+

Comment: :D indeed... I just bumped on this question and thought I would throw some updated suggestion (6 years later)

Answer (score 2):

This works for me

```
date_of_birth = forms.DateField(
    localize=True,
    widget=forms.DateInput(format = '%Y-%m-%d',attrs={'type': 'date'}),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set [USE_L10N](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#use-l10n) `False` as shown below to make [DATE_INPUT_FORMATS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#date-input-formats) work to change the date format of [DateTimeField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield) and [DateField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#datefield). *`USE_L10N` is prior to `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS` so you need to set `USE_L10N` `False`:

```py
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%d-%m-%Y')
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = False # Here
```

The doc says below in [DATE_INPUT_FORMATS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#date-input-formats):

> When `USE_L10N` is `True`, the locale-dictated format has higher precedence and will be applied instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would overwrite the DateTimeField put my our logic. It doesn't matter how postgresql is storing it, you can format it how ever you want.

Docs:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/

Comment: so django wont do this for me? I have to do it myself?

Comment: this might help: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/forms/fields/#datefield to keep it simple