# Django model date

Tags: python, django

How can I insert only the number of weeks and year to the date in the Django model? Because now, can I only add the normal date in format DD/MM/YYYY.

```
class Status(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField('Date')
```

Comment: posible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876370/django-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: Django Model supports strftime so you could check [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for your disired format

Comment: But I still dont know how to change the format of my DateField.

Comment: If I can understand you question correctly you want to store total no of weeks and corresponding year not the current week no. right ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand that datefield stores date, which is a object. So, in whichever format you want to input, you have to convert it to the date object. For example: If you insert a date in ww/yyyy:

forms.py

```
date_value= form.CharField() #When you render this form in template, use JQuery Mask to keep format.
#lets say it will get input like WW/YYYY
```

views.py

```
        date_value = datetime.strptime(str(request.POST['date_value'])+'/1', '%W/%Y/%w') #here week count starts from Monday
        new_status= Status()
        new_status.date= date_value
        new_status.save()
```

More details about .strptime [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Related questions: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882405/get-date-from-iso-week-number-in-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304256/whats-the-best-way-to-find-the-inverse-of-datetime-isocalendar)

Comment: But I dont want to insert date in DD/MM/YYYY but in format like WW/YYYY the WW characters represent week of the year.

Comment: can you give an example??

Comment: I would like to use only weeks and year in my project which will be defined in database through DateField. Like when I register an user and I only define there the week of the year of his registration and not the full date.

Comment: I'll give you my feedback after few tests.