# Django date filter not working in template

Tags: django, date, django-templates

I'm having problems with formatting a date object in a django template. In models.py the object looks like this:

```
release_date = models.DateField(blank=True,null=True)
```

In the database it looks like this:

```
[release_date] date,
```

The call in the template which does not work is this:

```
<td>{{ row.release_date|date:"Y-m-d" }}</td>
```

If I remove |date:"Y-m-d" the output looks like this:

```
08/04/2014
```

With |date:"Y-m-d" there is no date at all, but the rest of the site looks fine and there also is no error message in the console.

I already tried to convert the datetime object in views.py to a string but somehow the object still appears as a datetime object in the template. Here is what I did in views.py:

```
data=Release.objects.all().order_by('-release_date')
#convert dates to format YYYY-MM-DD since conversion does not work in the template
for data_item in data:
    if data_item.orig_plan_date is not None:
        data_item.orig_plan_date = data_item.orig_plan_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Does anybody know how I can fix this problem?

Comment: are the dashes between the letters valid syntax for django date formatting? I don't see any examples of dash usage in the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date

Comment: |date:"Y m d" doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4884923/1184321) post it looks like you can change the format your dates are saved into your DB so that you don't have to specify the way they are displayed.

In your situation I'd assume that if you edit your settings.py to include:

`DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%Y-%m-%d')`

and hooked it up to the form/modelform you use to save the date to the db. maybe something like:

`class YourDateModelformName(ModelForm):
    yourDateField = DateField(input_formats=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS)
    class Meta:
        model = YourDateModel`

Comment: I don't have a seperate form for this date object. I use the admin interface to input data. Interestingly the date is displayed there as 2014-08-06.

Comment: I finally got it to work. I set USE_L10N = False, which was before True and added SHORT_DATE_FORMAT = 'Y-m-d' in settings.py. Now I don't have to use the date filter in the template at all.