# ["'02-05-2020' value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format."]

Tags: python, django, date

I get the above error as I try to enter 02-05-2020 date in the database. I want the format of date entered to be DD-MM-YYYY and not YYYY-MM-DD. I am using DateField.

```
date = models.DateField()
```

Comment: Put it in the database the way it is supposed to be and then change the format when you display it.

Comment: set [**`DATE_INPUT_FORMATS`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#date-input-formats)

Comment: I also want to fetch it from database based on from date and to date (which comes from user input) for which I am using date__range(startDate, endDate).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django date format 'dd-mm-yyyy'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876370/django-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy)

Comment: @ArakkalAbu No I have already tried that solution.

Comment: Is that date supposed to be February 5th or May 2nd?

Comment: It is supposed to be May 2nd.

Comment: Anyways I did what @Nick suggested.

Comment: @Error in the long run you'll be happier you did. It will make it a lot easier to write queries against the values.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not detailed but try something like this:

```
import datetime

userinput = input("Enter Date DD-MM-YYYY") 
birthday = datetime.datetime.strptime(userinput, '%d-%m-%Y').date()
print(birthday)
```

Output:

```
2020-05-02
```

You need to specify the input format to the user, then you use the `strptime()` function to to convert it to  date format. See the `input format` above and see the `OUTPUT` above

**EDIT**

Here is how to do it in Django:

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
import datetime

# Create your models here.
class Calculator(models.Model):
    deadline = models.DateField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
         return self.deadline
```

forms.py

```
from .models import Calculator



class CalculatorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ''' remove any labels here if desired
        '''
    super(CalculatorForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


    # you can also remove labels of built-in model properties
    self.fields['deadline'].label = ''

    class Meta:
        model = Calculator
        fields = ['deadline']
        widgets = {
            'deadline': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'datepicker', 'placeholder': 'mm-dd-YYYY'})
        }
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.urls import reverse
from .forms import CalculatorForm
from .models import Calculator
import time
import datetime

# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    today = datetime.date.today()
    form = CalculatorForm(request.POST)
    # If this is a POST request then process the Form data

    if form.is_valid():
       instance = form.save()
       currentdate = datetime.date.today()
       userinput = str(instance.deadline) 
       birthday = datetime.datetime.strptime(userinput, '%d-%m-%Y').date()

       days = birthday - currentdate
       daysLeft = 'Days to your event is ' , days

       #return render(request, 'calculator/check.html', {'days':days})
       return HttpResponse(daysLeft)
    context = {
       'form': form,
    }
```

I used a simple date calculator to show how to do this in Django. I hope it solves your problem

Comment: By using **date=models.DateField** I can enter data in database in _YYYY-MM-DD_ format only but I want it to be entered in _DD-MM-YYYY_ format.

Comment: No I used models.DateFIield too. are you using Django or Flask?

Comment: I am using Django.